# How to determine if there exists an isomorphism to a subring of $\mathbb{R}$ from a ring and ideal.

Tags: abstract-algebra, galois-theory, ring-isomorphism

In my galois theory class, on a review sheet, my professor wrote:
Determine with proof whether the following rings are isomorphic to subrings of $\mathbb{R}$.

1. $\frac{\mathbb{Q}[x]}{<x^2-2x-2>}$
2. $\frac{\mathbb{Q}[x]}{<x^2-2x+1>}$
3. $\frac{\mathbb{Q}[x]}{<x^2-2x+2>}$

For (1), I understand that the ideal is irreducible, and hence we have a field. From this using that that any homomorphism $\phi:K\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ where $K$ is a field is an injection from $K$ to $\phi(K)$. My professor used that a homomorphism is uniquely determined by the image of $x$. If we let $\phi(x)=1+\sqrt{3}$, we define a homomorphism. Does $K$ need to be a field for this to be true? How can I be sure that his is a homomorphism as well? (my professor claimed that it is a homomorphism without checking, so I assume there is a reason.) Additionally, what sort of tools will I need for the remaining problems. I am sort of behind and I would really appreciate it if a sort of comprehensive set of tools for these problems could be given.

Comment: Basically you are asked whether the polynomials have real roots.

Comment: That is a much easier question to answer, but how did you come to that conclusion.

Comment: @Colebasaur, if $F$ is a field and $f \in F[x]$ is irreducible, then $F/ \langle f \rangle \cong F(\alpha)$, where $\alpha$ is a root of $f$.  In this problem, $\mathbb{Q}$ is a field and those quadratic polynomials are irreducible.

Comment: @KajHansen Could you help motivate a proof for me? Also, why is this not true for any ideal

Comment: If $f$ were reducible, the quotient ring $F/\langle f \rangle$ would have zero divisors.  In particular, if $f = gh$, then $g$ and $h$ are zero divisors.  Fields have no zero divisors, so there could be no isomorphism with $F(\alpha)$.  To prove that fact, let $\alpha$ be a root and consider the [first isomorphism theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isomorphism_theorems#Rings) w.r.t. the evaluation homomorphism $\text{ev}_\alpha: F[x] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ given by $f \mapsto f(\alpha)$.  What is the image?  The kernel?

Answer (score 1):

Let $K \subset F$ be fields and $f \in K[x]$ irreducible. Then I claim that $K[x]/(f)$ is isomorphic to a subfield of $F$ if and only if $f$ has a root in $F$.

On the one hand, $K[x]/(f)$ clearly contains a root of $f$. So if it is a subfield of $F$, $F$ clearly also contains a root of $f$.

On the other hand if $a \in F$ with $f(a)=0$, we have a well-defined injection $$K[x]/(f) \hookrightarrow F, x \mapsto a.$$

Comment: I do not understand how $x\mapsto a$ defines a homomorphism

Comment: This is how you define maps from the polynomial ring.

Comment: I was unclear. I do not understand why it is a homomorphism. I'm not convinced that, because $f(a)=0$, $K[x]/(f)\hookrightarrow F$ where $x\mapsto a$ is a homomorphism.

Comment: But you know that $K[x] \to F, x \mapsto a$ is a homomorphism?